# Is there any meaning for the name Nala?

Tags: name, sanskrit, nala

There is a [Nala](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03053.htm) in Mahabharata.

> Vrihadaswa said, "There was a king named **Nala**, the son of Virasena.
>   And he was strong, and handsome, and well-versed in (the knowledge of)
>   horses, and possessed of every desirable accomplishment. And he was at
>   the head of all the kings, even like the lord of the celestials. And
>   exalted over all, he resembled the sun in glory. And he was the king
>   of the Nishadhas, intent on the welfare of the Brahmanas, versed in
>   the Vedas, and possessed of heroism...

There is another [Nala](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga17/balasans17.htm#Verse12) in Ramayana too

> The brilliant Gandhamaadana is the son of Kubera, while the divine
>   architect Vishvakarma procreated the great monkey called **Nala**.

Is there any meaning to the name Nala?

Comment: One of the meaning of the Nala word is reed (several tall, grass-like plants of wetlands.) The word is found with similar meaning in Bhagvata Purana. But i am sure what they mean in keeping this name is "tall like grass or diverse as grass " etc. Also this is a name of An ancient hermit mentioned in MB.

Comment: Do you want scriptural meaning or the general one ?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar scriptural, if there else general...

Comment: may be lotus or white..